# Android Device monitor disabled

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm just getting started with Android development and was setting up [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) on my mac. (Following the instructions [here](http://vimeo.com/113893631))

When trying to run a simple hello world application and trying to learn my way around the IDE, I noticed the "Android Device monitor" disabled. Any ideas how I can fix this? This should be important when debugging apps hence the question.

[image]

I'm not sure what other info might be important for this question. I did make a few changes in the SDK manager, but they were just installing more components on top of what was already installed.

Answer (score 3):

Once you open a valid project, the buttons become enabled.

Note that, even if the option is disabled, you can still bring up the Device Monitor by running the **monitor.bat** file in the **tools** directory of the Android SDK. (On Windows you can just double click the file or run it from a cmd shell.)

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurs to me today. And I just click the button on the pic. 
Problem solved.

[image]

and If this didn't work ,you can check this list in your Android Studio

1.Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration

2.If you open DDMS, CLOSE it .

If these didn't work too, check the official file. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html

Comment: @Mohammad thanks, I'm new here. Just now I was wondering why my pic didn't render out.